# Why does `Repeated` not work in this case?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I think I don't understand how to use `Repeated`.

I have a list for example

```
list={a,b,a,b,a,b,a,a,b}
```

I want to detect whether this list has repeated element a,a or b,b

I tried

```
Cases[list, Repeated[a,{2}]]
```

It doesn't work, why? How to do this?

Comment: Think about it - what are the *cases* that are tested? It's the *elements* of the list. Try, e.g., `Cases[list, x_ /; (Print@x; True)]` and see what you get. `Cases[Split@list, {Repeated[a | b, {2}]}]` will spit out a list of matches, 
`MemberQ[Split@list, {Repeated[a | b, {2}]}]` will return `True` or `False` if any are there (you said "detect", hence I'm guessing that's what you meant.) There are other ways, that should get you started.

Comment: @ciao Thank you very much. I got the point

Comment: @ciao Might be good to post that comment as an answer. Else the question could get closed. Strikes me as the sort of thing that can be confusing and so maybe ought to be kept, with a response of course.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau : done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per request by the Pope:

Think about it - what are the cases that are tested?

It's the ***elements*** of the list.

Try, e.g., `Cases[list, x_ /; (Print@x; True)]` and see what you get (it will show that the test is done on an element-by-element basis).

`Cases[Split@list, {Repeated[a | b, {2}]}]` will spit out a list of matches, `MemberQ[Split@list, {Repeated[a | b, {2}]}]` will return True or False if any are there (you said "detect", hence I'm guessing that's what you meant.)

There are other ways, that should get you started.

Btw- putting a `Print` (or `Sow`, etc.) temporarily as part of a test/rule/etc. can be a quite handy debugging and learning tool - I use it every now and then when a complex rule and/or test is not doing what I think it should (and inevitably, it's my thinking that was off).

Answer (score 5):

*Why* part is explained nicely in @ciao's answer. This post deals with the part:

> *I want to detect whether this list has repeated element a,a or b,b*

You can get what you expected to get from `Cases[...]` using the new-in-v-10 function `SequenceCases`:

```
list={a,b,a,b,b,b,a,b,a,a,b};
SequenceCases[list,{Repeated[x_,{2}]}]
```

> {{b, b}, {a, a}}

Or, define a `Boolean` function that returns `True` when the input list contains repeated elements:

```
containsRepeatedQ = SequenceCases[#,{Repeated[x_,{#2}]}] != {}&;

containsRepeatedQ[{a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b}, 2]
```

> False

```
containsRepeatedQ[{a,b,a,b,a,b,a,a,b}, 2]
```

> True

Comment: Hi, kglr. Thank you introducing this new feature! Very useful